# How to noindex a text for search engines?

Tags: html, seo, google-search

I have in my site some text that is repeated multiple times in the same page in different areas. From seo perspective I heard this is not a good idea to have duplicated content. Is there a way to resolve this without removing the text? The text is not intended for seo anyway.

One idea that I had is to use the "hidden" html5 attribute, and change the styling to display:block in css, hoping that google will skip whenever hidden is used. But I'm not sure if this will work...

Comment: read the [tag:seo] tag wiki.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use display:none, still Google can access it.

You have many options to use:

1. You can load the text via Ajax, in this case Google will not see the text
2. You can use iframe from another page
3. Use the text as images